# How to convert String object to Date object?

Tags: java, date

How can I convert a String object to a Date object?

I think I need to do something like this:

```
Date d=(some conversion ) "String "
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("1.1.2001");
```

For details refer to:  [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I think you're missing a 'y' or two.

Comment: yyou were right, thx for the note.

Answer (score 9):

Date-to-String conversion is a relatively complex parsing operation, not something you can do with a simple cast as you are trying.

You'll have to use a [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). It can be as simple as:

```
Date d = DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse("09/10/2009");
```

But this changes the expected date format depending on the locale settings of the machine it's running on. If you have a specific date format, you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm").parse("4 Jul 2001 12:08");
```

Note that the parse method will always expect one specific format, and will not try to guess what could be meant if it receives a different format.

Answer (score 4):

See [Sun's Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) and the class SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 3):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` with a format string, which matches your actual format:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d = sdf.parse("2009-10-09");
```

Answer (score 3):

[java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that extends java.text.DateFormat abstract class.

```
 DateFormat MYDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
 Date today = MYDate.parse("09/10/2009");
```

Answer (score 1):

you should parse the string with the SimpleDateFormat class

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Date date = DateFormat.getInstance.parse( dateString );
```

Comment: That gives you no control at all over what the format of the string should look like, so this is unlikely to be useful. Better use `SimpleDateFormat`, which allows you to specify the format to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert String object into Date object using this method. and this Java code is tested and running component in my environment.

```
public static Date parseStringAsDate(String dateStr, String format) throws ParseException
{
    if(null==dateStr || "".equals(dateStr))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("dateStr must not be null or empty");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return df.parse(dateStr);
}
```

dateStr = "17/05/2017"

format= "dd/MM/yyyy"