# convert string date to a date object

Tags: java

How can this 11/03/2009-20:06:16 to a Date object so I can compare two dates. I keep getting  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date error if I use below implementation.. I need the output to be date object with format Tue Jul 14 01:32:31 2009

```
  import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Dateaf {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String text = "11/03/2009-20:06:16";

        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy-hh:mm:ss");

        Date date = dateParser.parse(text);
        System.out.println(date);

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543481/how-to-convert-string-object-to-date-object

Answer (score 3):

`sdf.format()` takes a `Date` object and returns a `String`. You are passing a `String` to it.

Comment: I need the output to be date object with format Tue Jul 14 01:32:31 2009

Comment: The date object has no format, it is just a `long` with the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the `String` to `Date`, and **another `SimpleDateFormat`** to convert the `Date` to the `String` with the desired format.

Comment: I get this error Unparseable date: "11-03-2009 20:06:16"..

Comment: I need the date object to be Tue Jul 14 01:32:31 2009. how can I do that?

Comment: You need to you `HH` for 24 hour clock rather than `hh` - that's 12 hour.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close, just drop the call to `format`:

```
Date date = sdf.parse(text);
```

So:

```
String text = "11-03-2009 20:06:16";

SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                                             //^^ capital H for 24 hour  

Date date = dateParser.parse(text);
```

And to print (from your comment in the format "Tue Jul 14 01:32:31 2009"):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");

System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
```

The [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is an excellent reference for formats.

**EDIT**

After OP's edits here is a full example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String text = "11/03/2009-20:06:16";
    final SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ss");
    final Date date = dateParser.parse(text);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
}
```

Output:

```
Tue Nov 03 20:06:16 2009
```

Comment: If the hypen to this / what would be the change?

Comment: In the incoming format? change `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: one more problem HH and hh has not effect I have updated the code..

Answer (score -1):

Java has the text package which gives us the predefined class text

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date today = df.parse("20/12/2005");
System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
}
}
```

There is another way of doing this

```
String date = "2000-11-01";
java.sql.Date javaSqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
```

Comment: Please add more detail